# document.getElementById won’t work, how do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have this site that converts a quadratic equation to the vertex form.

What I did was add a form with inputs where you can add in the variables required to convert the equation. I am almost done with it, but when I try to call `getElementById` with the IDs `h` and `k`, the document can’t because it was defined after the user hits the submit button, therefore I cannot load the function on startup which would have solved my problem.

```js
function abc(a, b, c) {
  var a_el = document.getElementById('a');
  var b_el = document.getElementById('b');
  var c_el = document.getElementById('c');
  var av = a_el.value;
  var bv = b_el.value;
  var cv = c_el.value;
  console.log(av);
  console.log(bv);
  console.log(cv);
  var h = (-1 * bv) / (2 * av);
  console.log(h);
  var k = (av * (Math.pow(h, 2))) + (bv * h) + cv;
  console.log(k);
  document.getElementById("av").innerHTML = av;
  document.getElementById("bv").innerHTML = bv;
  document.getElementById("cv").innerHTML = cv;
  document.getElementById("h").innerHTML = h;
  document.getElementById("k").innerHTML = k;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>a:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="a">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>b:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="b">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>c:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="c">
  </div>
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="abc();"></input>
</form>
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <mi>f</mi>
  <mo>(</mo>
  <mi>x</mi>
  <mo>)</mo>
  <mo>=</mo>
  <mn id="av"></mn>
  <msup>
    <mrow>
      <mo>(</mo>
      <mi>x</mi>
      <mo>-</mo>
      <mn id="h"></mn>
      <mo>)</mo>
    </mrow>
    <mrow>
      <mn>2</mn>
    </mrow>
  </msup>
  <mo>+</mo>
  <mn id="k"></mn>
  <math>

    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
      <img src="quad.png" class="img-rounded pull-right thumbnail">
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: `bv` and `cv` aren't defined in the html! Try defining them!

Comment: i will add that the a variable does work for whatever reason

Comment: @acesmndr thanks for the help, but im confused, where would this be at and did i do it with av?

Comment: I just meant that you hadn't defined any HTML tags with `bv` and `cv` ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not working in the code snippet mostly because some of the tags with IDs were not defined and also because the JavaScript is automatically enclosed inside a self executing anonymous function `(function(){})()` in the code snippet *in Stack Overflow* thus the `abc` function was undefined when the `onclick` handler was added. Thus adding a `click` event listener in JavaScript resolved this issue as well. This was solely to make it run in the code snippet in Stack Overflow.

You can delegate the `onclick` event or you could embed the script inside a `<script>` tag and add it to the HTML.

```js
(function(){
  function abc() {
    var a_el = document.getElementById('a');
    var b_el = document.getElementById('b');
    var c_el = document.getElementById('c');
    var av = a_el.value;
    var bv = b_el.value;
    var cv = c_el.value;
    console.log(av);
    console.log(bv);
    console.log(cv);
    var h = (-1 * bv) / (2 * av);
    console.log(h);
    var k = (av * (Math.pow(h, 2))) + (bv * h) + cv;
    console.log(k);
    document.getElementById("av").innerHTML = av;
    document.getElementById("h").innerHTML = h;
    document.getElementById("k").innerHTML = k;
  }
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click",function(){
  abc();
});
})();
```

```html
<form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>a:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="a">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>b:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="b">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>c:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="c">
                </div>
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="submit"       value="Submit" id="submit"></input>
            </form>
            <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
                <mi>f</mi>
                <mo>(</mo>
                <mi>x</mi>
                <mo>)</mo>
                <mo>=</mo>
                <mn id="av"></mn>
                <msup>
                    <mrow>
                        <mo>(</mo>
                        <mi>x</mi>
                        <mo>-</mo>
                        <mn id="h"></mn>
                        <mo>)</mo>
                    </mrow>
                    <mrow>
                        <mn>2</mn>
                    </mrow>
                </msup>
                <mo>+</mo>
                <mi id="k"></mi>
                <math>

    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <img src="quad.png" class="img-rounded pull-right thumbnail">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: how is this delegating anything ... and the fact this works is because you removed the code that tried to get non-existent elements.

Comment: @JaromandaX I just meant that we could use the addEventListener to delegate events instead of adding the onclick handler on the page as in the code snippet the javascript is added after the page has finished loading i.e. it is enclosed in `(function(){})()`. The `abc` function is undefined when the `onclick` handler is added through html. I just wanted to address this issue as well.